# Crontab in order after completed

Tags: cron

Is it possible to make crontab run after one's execution. I read that cron jobs start from top, but run parallel, doesn't wait one to finish.
Is there any way that I can do like this?
For example, let's say I have 3 cron jobs.

- `*/5 * * * * job1`
- `*/5 * * * * job2`
- `*/5 * * * * job3`

I want job2 to run after job1 has completed, and job3 after job2 completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have more than one command in a single crontab entry:

```
*/5 * * * * job1 ; job2 ; job3
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, does that mean jobs going to start after the previous job has completed?

Comment: Yes, they will run in sequence as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use the global crontab in **/etc**, it's simpler.
The main crontab file is **/etc/crontab**. It contains this type of instruction:

```
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

so Linux uses **run-parts**; run-parts launch commands in alphabetical order, so just add numbers in the script like this:

- 01_MyFisrtScrip
- 02_MySecondScript
- ...

and so on... Please avoid using dots or other characters that are not legal for run-parts:

- BAD NAME = 01_myscript.sh
- GOOD NAME = 01_myscript